# Another Simple LINQ to XML query

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

This one is my XML

```
 Dim X = <BODY>
   <HEAD1>
    <Eyes>BLUE</Eyes>
   </HEAD1>
   <HEAD2>
    <Eyes>BROWN</Eyes>
   </HEAD2>
   </BODY>
```

Until now i managed to get the HEAD parts.
Now how can i iterate within the HEAD parts?

```
 Dim HEADS = From element In X.Elements Select element.Name.LocalName
 For Each c In HEADS
   Dim Local As String = c
   Dim COLORSofEYES = SELECT child nodes WHERE c 'Something like that i guess
 Next
```

The above should return on first iterattion
`<Eyes>BLUE</Eyes>` as ElementNodeType and on the second `<Eyes>BROWN</Eyes>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

```
Dim COLORSofEYES = From d In X.Descendants(Local).Descendants Select d
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code (in C#):

```
        var x = XElement.Parse(
            @"<BODY>    
              <HEAD1>     <Eyes>BLUE</Eyes>    </HEAD1>    
              <HEAD2>     <Eyes>BROWN</Eyes>    </HEAD2>    </BODY>");

        foreach(var head in x.Elements())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("head: {0}, eyes' colour: {1}", head.Name.LocalName, head.Element("Eyes").Value);
        }
```

will produce the following output:

```
head: HEAD1, eyes' colour: BLUE
head: HEAD2, eyes' colour: BROWN
```

Which I understand is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd format.  I'm not sure what exactly you want to iterate over.  If you just want to iterate over all `<Eyes>`, you could just do this:

```
Dim query = X...<Eyes>
```

Otherwise if you just want to get all the children of each `<HEAD...>`, you could do this:

```
Dim query = X.Elements.SelectMany(Function(e) e.Elements)
```

Or with XPath:

```
Dim query = X.XPathSelectElements("/*/*")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write it in a single LINQ query

in `C#`

```
IEnumerable<XElement> de = from p in xmlTree.Elements().Elements() 
                            select p;
```

output

```
<Eyes>BLUE</Eyes>

<Eyes>BROWN</Eyes>
```

Hope i got your question properly.

Note: in your case you can use `Descendants` also

```
Descendants: yield entire child and sub-tree
Elements   :  yield through only through your child
```